# Calculate a difficult integral with the help of the Theorem of Fubini

Tags: integration, fubini-tonelli-theorems

How would you possibly calculate this integral?

$$ \int\limits_0^\infty e^{-y} \cdot \frac{ (\sin(y) )^2 }{ y } dy $$

I suppose that the solution involves applying the Theorem of Fubini. I attach the whole exercise as an image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, let's solve this integral:

$$\mathcal{I}:=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\displaystyle\exp\left(-x\right)\sin^2\left(x\right)}{\displaystyle x}\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Now, when we apply [the evaluating integrals over the positive real axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis) property of the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform), we can write:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{1}
\mathcal{I}&=\int\limits_0^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\frac{\displaystyle\sin^2\left(x\right)}{\displaystyle x}\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x^{-1}\left[\exp\left(-x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty\left(\int\limits_\sigma^\infty\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sin^2\left(x\right)\right]_{\left(\tau\right)}\space\text{d}\tau\right)\cdot\mathscr{L}_x^{-1}\left[\exp\left(-x\right)\right]_{\left(\sigma\right)}\space\text{d}\sigma\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty\left(\int\limits_\sigma^\infty\frac{\displaystyle2}{\displaystyle\tau^3+4\tau}\space\text{d}\tau\right)\cdot\delta\left(\sigma-1\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty\left(\frac{\displaystyle\ln\left(4+\sigma^2\right)-2\ln\left(\sigma\right)}{\displaystyle4}\right)\cdot\delta\left(\sigma-1\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\\
\\
&=\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\displaystyle\ln\left(4+\sigma^2\right)-2\ln\left(\sigma\right)}{\displaystyle4}\cdot\delta\left(\sigma-1\right)\space\text{d}\sigma\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\ln\left(4+1^2\right)-2\ln\left(1\right)}{\displaystyle4}\\
\\
&=\frac{\displaystyle\ln\left(5\right)}{\displaystyle4}
\end{alignat*}
\tag2
$$

Where I used the fact that:

$$\int\limits_0^\infty\text{y}\left(x\right)\delta\left(x-1\right)\space\text{d}x=\text{y}\left(1\right)\tag3$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know that method of computer an integral over the positive real axis.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation of the inner integral gives
$$\int\limits_0^1 h(x,y) dx = e^{-y} \cdot (-1) \cdot \frac{\cos(2y) - 1}{2y} = e^{-y} \cdot (-1) \cdot \frac{\cos^2(y) - \sin^2(y) - 1}{2y} = e^{-y} \cdot (-1) \cdot \frac{\cos^2(y) - \sin^2(y) - 1}{2y} = e^{-y} \cdot \frac{\sin^2(y)}{y}$$,
so the value of the original integral would be $\ln(5)$ if you use the result of exercise 3

Comment: A simpler way to see that you need integrate $h$ is the fact that $\sin (2a)=2\sin (a)\cos (a)$, which is of the form $2*f*f'$ and thus is the differential of $f^2$. I think this is a bit more intuitive.